# Correct Syntax for Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

Goal:
The url should be "https://localhost:44353/api/Authentication/Validate?a=aa&b=bb"

Problem:
What syntax code am I missing in relation to web api?

Thank you!

```
// https://localhost:44353/api/Authentication/Validate/c/c
[HttpGet("Validate/{a}/{b}")]
public bool Validate(string a, string b)
{
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: As joel has said, you just need to use `[HttpGet("Validate")]` .What else questions do you have?

Comment: No more questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parameters don't need to be specified in the route pattern. The following should be enough to achieve the goal URL:

```
[HttpGet("Validate")]
public IActionResult Validate(string a, string b)
{
    return Ok(false);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a url link?

Comment: If this link don't work "https://localhost:44353/api/Authentication/Validate?a=aa&b=bb". What link should it be?

Comment: If yoiu mean to use "https://localhost:44353/api/Authentication/Validate/c/c" instead of using "localhost:44353/api/Authentication/Validate?a=aa&b=bb"?

Comment: Updated the solution to include the Validate name for the route.